# AbstractMethodError when invoking createArrayOf, with postgresql 8.4 jdbc4 and JBoss 5.1GA

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss

when using this method

```
public List<Field> getFieldWithoutId(List<Integer> idSections) throws Exception {
    try {
        Connection conn = this.getConnection();
        Array arraySections = conn.createArrayOf("int4", idSections.toArray());
        this.log.info("Recupero field");
        List<Field> fields = this.getJdbcTemplate().query(getFieldWithoutIdQuery, new Object[] {arraySections},ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Field.class));
        /*if (!conn.isClosed())
            conn.close();
        */
        releaseConnection(conn);
        return fields;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Errore.");
    }
}
```

I have an exception at `conn.createArrayOf("int4", idSections.toArray());`.

The exception is:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException : Unexpected Error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk5.WrappedConnectionJDK5.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
```

`postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar` is in `jboss/server/all/lib` dir. Application is spring based with ejb3.

When working locally with the same setup everything is fine. This only happens on a preproduction environment. Only difference is locally I have jboss run in default mode, in the other case there are 2 jbosses in all configuration. I can't track down the cause of this error. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [java.lang.AbstractMethodError](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

This means that an abstract method which is declared in some API in the current runtime classpath is missing in the *concrete* implementation in the current runtime classpath.

> org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk5.WrappedConnectionJDK5.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;

Given the fact that it works fine in local environment, but not in preproduction environment, it would mean that the environments are using a different JBoss server version and/or that the deployed webapplication unnecessarily contains JBoss-specific libraries in the `/WEB-INF/lib`. At least, the classpath is messed up. Cleanup it.

Comment: JBoss version is the same, and EAR content is this :

1) lib folder with ejbclient.jar with no libraries
2) META-INF folder with Manifest
3) backend.jar that contains :
   1) META-INF folder with manifest and spring config files
4) one webapp, currently almost empty, with no libraries anyway

Could you point me to the right way of cleaning classpath?

Comment: Just go through all paths covered by the webapp's classpath, check if you don't see version collisions in JAR files with same classes. Maybe those libraries are in the `/JRE/lib` or `/JRE/lib/ext`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just hit this:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=730588